# nginx: [warn] conflicting server name ip_address on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger, web-deployment

I have install Nginx and Passenger using [How To Deploy a Rails App with Passenger and Nginx](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-rails-app-with-passenger-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04). I did everything as per the blog. But when I reload Nginx service `sudo nginx -s reload` it is showing `nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "ip_address" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored`

**/etc/site-available/default**

```
server {
        #listen 80;
        #listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;

        server_name ip_address;
        passenger_enabled on;
        rails_env    production;
        root         /var/www/testapp/public;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
}
```

**/etc/site-available/testapp**

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  server_name ipaddress;
  passenger_enabled on;
  passenger_app_env development;
  root /home/iradmin/rails_project/testapp/public;
}
```

I don't know what I have done wrong in here. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

In your `/etc/sites-available/default` config you have set `server_name` to `ipaddress` and in `/etc/sites-available/testapp` you have also given a `server_name` of `ipaddress`.

The error message states that you have a conflict because in both files - the server name is `ipaddress`. To resolve this error, give your servers different names. More information on Nginx server_name can be found in the official docs [here.](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html)

Comment: Previously I had a webruby file in site-available folder like testapp with same setup but i deleted that file to setup the new file testapp. Is the error may coming because of that file removed?